# Practical Uses of Laser Attenuation

Tags: laser

In my college physics lab, I am studying the attenuation of a laser through different concentrations of copper sulfate. I am curious about the practical uses of laser attenuation. Why do we study it? Just to see how much power will be lost? Or do we ever purposefully attenuate lasers?

I'm curious if there are any common, or everyday uses, and also what are the uses in more advanced technologies and theories?

Comment: The first application that I have in mind is passing the laser through a delicate sample that can't withstand a high power laser

Comment: Since you seem to be asking how useful attenuation is *for the laser*, and I don't know the answer to that, I'll just leave this as a comment: How light changes in a material can tell you a lot *about the material*. For instance, measuring concentration via Beer-Lambert. Or measuring chirality via optical activity.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I think the question is how useful attenuation is _for human_, not for the laser, so your comment can well be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are measuring laser attenuation $\frac{I}{I_0}$ vs. concentration $c$, it is almost certain that you are studying laser attenuation in order to see the [Beer-Lambert Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) in action (as Chris White alludes to in a comment):

$log_{10}\frac{I_0}{I}=\epsilon cL$

"Seeing how much power is lost" is exactly how a [UV/Vis spectrophotometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet%E2%80%93visible_spectroscopy) calculates the concentration of a solution. Chemists can use this data to determine the rates of chemical reactions, as they are dependent on concentration.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it if you are studying single photon physics, or testing (say) photo-amplifiers.